# UML dynamic class association

Tags: uml

I have a class called `pet`, which is dynamically associated to either 1 `dog` or `cat` but not both at the same time.

What's the name for this type of dynamic association? How can I represent this in a UML class diagram while making it clear that each `pet` is associated to either one `dog` or `cat` but not both at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is what you're after simply inheritance? *Pet* seems to me to be an abstract concept, where as Dog and Cat would be concrete concepts. My initial solution in your situation would probably be to have an abstract *Pet* class (which cannot be instantiated) which is specialized to Dog and Cat (which can).

If you are really keen to have an instance of a *Pet* which is associated with an instance of either a Cat or a Dog, then you'd probably have to manage this by inheritance anyway. Something like this perhaps: [image]

Comment: thanks. what if I want to associate pet with another completely different object like 'Couch'. But it should only ever be associated to either 1 Animal or 1 Couch but not both

Comment: Humm, well I think it is probably a task to figure out what the highest level of abstraction is that you need in that relationship. At the most abstract you could I suppose associate Pet with an 'Object' which would serve as the highest level of abstraction and could be derived to literally anything. I'm not sure what Couches and Animals have in common, apart from they are both objects and Animals have an affinity with Couches :-) .

Comment: Great answer. Only the multiplicity 0..* is weird. It means that an animal may be associated with multiple pets at the same time. I think the multiplicity should be 0..1.

Comment: If the multiplicity was 0..1 or 1 on the Pet side then logically the Animal and the Pet are the same thing (i.e. a 1 to 1 relationship) therefore there'd be no point in separating Pet from Animal. This was my reasoning anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of your question is bit funny when reading it as a model of the real world (a *domain model*).

In the real world, a pet is ***not associated*** with an animal. Rather, a pet ***IS*** an animal. Consequently, the class `pets` is a (role) subclass of `animals`, in a domain model, based on the meaning of the term "pet" in English.

The concept of role classes is not very well supported by mainstream OOP languages. An object may play many roles (that is, instantiate many role classes) at the same time (multiple classification) and it may cease to play a role, that is, cease to instantiate the corresponding role class (dynamic classification).

Maybe you are not interested in making a domain model first, before making a (technology-independent) *design model*, which you may then turn, e.g., into a Java or C# class model.

Maybe you want to jump to a C++ class model directly, without first trying to understand the underlying domain concepts.

You can do this, but I don't think it's a good idea.